# Accessing HTML Elements From Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have the following HTML code

```
<input type="text" readonly name="Name" class="GadgetName" placeholder="Please Enter the Gadget Name" value="Potatoe Masher" />
<input type="text" readonly name="Description" class="GadgetDescription" placeholder="Please Enter the Gadget Description" value="You'll Never Stop Mashing !" />
<form action="SubmitComment" method="POST">
    <div class="Comment">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="200" name="Comment" class="GadgetComment" id="Comment2" placeholder="Write Comments Here"></textarea>
        <input type="button" value="Submit Comment" class="CommentButton" onclick="AddComment()" />
    </div><br />
</form>
```

I need to access the text in the read only textbox `Name` and the text in the `Comment` textarea.

Note, that these lines are in a for loop hence there are multiple components with the same class name.

I managed to get the value in the `Comment` textarea using this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".CommentButton", function(){
        text = $("textarea", $(this).parent()).val();
    });
});
```

What I need now is to access the text in the `Name` textbox.

Comment: `$('.GadgetName').val()?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you do it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.CommentButton').click(function () {
    console.log($(this).closest('form').parent().find('[name="Name"]').val());
    console.log($(this).parent().find('[name="Comment"]').val());
  });
});
```

You can try it out in [action](http://jsfiddle.net/NsVKW/7/) as well.

Comment: I corrected the code for multiple items. And it does't require additional markup like with insomiac's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways:

1. From using input name..

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {

   $(document).on("click", ".CommentButton", function () {   
       text    =   $("textarea", $(this).parent()).val();
       var name = $("input[name='Name']").val();
       var description = $("input[name='Description']").val();
      });
   });
   ```

OR

2 By using class name :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on("click", ".CommentButton", function () {   
        text    =   $("textarea", $(this).parent()).val();
        var name = $(".GadgetName").val();
        var description = $(".GadgetDescription").val();
       });
    });
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KZ9hx/1/

Comment: Hi Unfortunetly, it Did not work,

What the First solution Did is the when applied to multiple Products; the Text changes when the respective button is pressed, but the name and description still displays the content of the first item.

The Second solution also only displays the first Item's Description and Name

Comment: can you post your complete html so that i can help you ?

Comment: check my updated answer and check the jsfiddle url.  I think i fixed your issue.